# Constructing a tuple (or list) from already-existing objects - what is the cost?

Tags: haskell, tuples

Suppose we have a function like this one:

```
foo (x, _, y) = (x, y)
```

What it does is, it takes a 3-tuple and returns a pair consisting of the first and third elements of the original tuple.

Now suppose we were to pass this function a 3-tuple consisting of some heavyweight objects. Would the two objects be copied to create a new tuple, or does the tuple's internal representation contain only references to objects?

I figure that, since data in Haskell is immutable, no additional copying would be needed, but I just want to be sure.

If this behavior is implementation-defined, I'd like to know what different implementations do in such cases.

Comment: `foo (Just x', _, Just y') = (Just x', Just y')` this may re-construct the two 'Just', but x' & y' will not be copied;   and `foo  (x@(Just x'), _, y@(Just y')) = (x, y)` may be more effective. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will be references - or not even that, but just a thunk. Haskell's lazy evaluation means it'll basically just remove the _ from the expression that will be expanded if you ever require its value. It's no different than basic functions like fst and snd.

Comment: The only object that is going to be rewritten is the tuple constructor.

Answer (score 4):

`x` and `y` are pointers to the values (or, if the values haven't been evaluated yet, to the [thunks](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Thunk)). Only the pointers are copied, the values not. Basically it's implementation defined, however this is how all implementations do it as this way you can implement [lazy evaluation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lazy_vs._non-strict), where the value is only evaluated at most once.